# Button Click Selects all checkboxes in DataGrid Rows in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox, textbox

```
[x] ID Name 
[x] 1  abc
[x] 2  def
[x] 3  xyz
selectAll  ClearAll
```

The above show a listview with columns of checkbox and with ID and Name columns. [x] is checkbox..i am doing this in WPF.

i want when i click on select all button everyrow of checkbox is selected and when clear all it will clear all checkboxes to false.. Please is there any complete tutorial or example solve plese share..

Comment: So, is this about a DataGrid or a Listview?

Comment: I am using Listview and i want with listview

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want this in WPF

Answer (score 1):

In the button handlers for your buttons you need the following code:

```
foreach (var item in dataSource)
{
    item.Checked = true;  // or false for ClearAll
}
```

You change the values in the source data and the UI will update to reflect that change.

If you haven't already, you need to set up a handler for the button click - this can be either a command or a click handler. Which one will depend on how you have structured your application.

The code goes inside those handlers.